# Windows CE 5.0 emulator needed

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-7, windows-ce, emulation, mobile-devices

I need an emulator for Windows CE 5.0 to test an embedded device (not PDA or smartphone) application that I am developing. This is what I have already tried:

- Visual Studio 2008 Pro includes an emulator. Unfortunately, it does not include a Windows CE image (only Windows Mobile and Smartphone). Yes, there is a difference, see [the screenshots here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200920152947/http://geekswithblogs.net/claraoscura/archive/2009/05/07/131872.aspx). Windows CE includes a "start button", windows that can be minimized, moved around etc.
- There is a [Windows CE Device Emulator](https://web.archive.org/web/20100908034224/http://www.microsoft.com:80/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=A120E012-CA31-4BE9-A3BF-B9BF4F64CE72&displaylang=en) available from Microsoft. Apart from the fact that its license only permits non-commercial use, it does not run in Windows 7 (it requires .net Framework 1.1, which is incompatible with Windows 7) nor in Windows XP mode (error message: "Emulator for Windows CE will not run one virtual machine within another. Please run the virtual machine on the host operating system").

Is there any option that I have missed?

Comment: Since when is .net framework 1.1 incompatible with Windows 7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried running [Microsoft VirtualPC](https://web.archive.org/web/20100909142424/http://www.microsoft.com:80/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=04D26402-3199-48A3-AFA2-2DC0B40A73B6&displaylang=en) along with the Windows CE6 [image](https://web.archive.org/web/20101228190428/http://code.msdn.microsoft.com:80/CE6VirtualPCBSP) or some other image for the version you are using

I have not tried this myself, but it seems to work. (from my google/youtube searches)

Comment: He asked about CE 5.0 specifically.

Comment: Indeed. it certainly helps when I read things. But Windows VirtualPC should work for a CE5 .vhd image as well.

Comment: @gruntled: this is a BSP for the emulator, not an emulator itself, which assumes that he has Platform Builder and knows how to generate an OS image for the emulator.  There isn't a BSP for VirtualPC for 5.0 that I'm aware of.

Comment: well yes. I haven't had a chance to actually read what the policies are for stackoverflow. but i didn't want to link to a torrent or anything for windows ce. Since i'm sure you would need a license.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the option you've missed is that you can create your own CE image for the emulator with the [emulator BSP](https://web.archive.org/web/20100816030246/http://www.microsoft.com:80/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=474B03A6-E87D-455D-BC16-B8CF18EF39B4&displaylang=en).  You then generate an image and run it with [Device Emulator 3.0](https://web.archive.org/web/20100906022459/http://www.microsoft.com:80/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=A6F6ADAF-12E3-4B2F-A394-356E2C2FB114&displaylang=en).

The reason Microsoft no longer ships a CE  emulator image is that there is no such thing as a "standard" Windows CE OS image.  Generally speaking you create an image that matches whatever you've got on your specific target hardware.

Comment: The `Emulator BSP` link is now broken. Microsoft appears to be slowly removing these older links as they push later version of their embedded OSes. Do you know where you can get or generate a CE image? Is it possible to generate it from your own device (perhaps using tools in VS 2005 or 2008)?