# Windows CE emulator for Win 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-ce, emulation

I am looking for a Windows 6 CE emulator, which I can use on my X86 32bit Win 7 Laptop. I just want to run a particular Win CE 7 software I have got on this Laptop.

I found a few emulators, but all fail. Some are not Win 7 compatible, others just do not start. Who can tell me an Win 7 emulator working on Win 7?

Comment: Have you tried running an emulator in XP-compatible mode? CE is a dead duck; you may be stuck running it in a VM.

Comment: Depending on the software, it may be possible to run it in some other operating system which is Windows CE based, for example Windows Mobile or Pocket PC emulators?

Comment: Thanks for the hints. Right, it is an outdated software. But I need to run a particular CE software - we give device emulator 3.0 a trial.

Comment: @David: what do you mean by "CE is a dead duck"?  It's a supported OS and version 7.0 was just released this week, so it's also quite current.

Comment: Yes you are right, just found the info. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the version 3.0 [of the Device Emulator](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/de-de/details.aspx?FamilyID=A6F6ADAF-12E3-4B2F-A394-356E2C2FB114) allowing me to run the emulator independently from VS2005.

Also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004853/windows-ce-5-0-emulator-needed) contains some more details, for me the VirtualPC image described there did not work with Win7.

Answer (score 2):

I made a windows xp VM and ran the emulator on that. Bit laggy, but it works.